# Remove class from parent when child span text is 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I load a span ".bubble" into the span ".auction-count" on my website:

```
$(function(){
  $(".auction-count").load("/eqdkp_plus/Guildbank.html .bubble");
});
```

So far so good.

If I then try to remove the class "non-zero" from the parent li if the text of the child span ".bubble" is 0 nothing happens.
It works fine at fiddle but not at my actual website.

HTML

```
<li class="tab auktionen non-zero" title="Auktionen ()">
    <a class="nav-link" href="/auktionen">Auktionen</a>
    <strong>
        <span class="counter auction-count"><span class="bubble">0</span></span>
    </strong>
</li>
```

CSS

```
.auktionen{
  background: none;
}
.non-zero, .non-zero a{
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: red;
  width: 120px;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

JS - ready(function()

```
var value = $('.bubble').text() == "0";
  if (!value) {
    $('li.auktionen').removeAttr("title");
  } else {
    alert( "Count value is 0!" );
    $('span.counter.auction-count').remove();
    $('li.auktionen').removeClass('non-zero').removeAttr("title");
  }
```

Here is my example: https://jsfiddle.net/Neverlands/aov7Ldpw/50/#&togetherjs=cO6QExBT6t

**Update:**
I have managed to remove classes and attributes now, but obviously I cannot differentiate if the innerHTML value of the ".bubble" span is 0 or another figure.

I just would need help with this part:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var value = document.getElementsByClassName("bubble").innerHTML = "0";
        if (!value) {
            alert( "The count value is at least 1" );
        } else {
            alert( "The count value is 0" );
    }
});
```

Comment: is class change already working ?

Comment: == instead of = , document.getElementsByClassName("bubble").innerHTML == "0"

Comment: @zod Yes, it is working.

Comment: @EvikGhazarian you mean 
var value = document.getElementsByClassName("bubble").innerHTML == "0";? 
This always alerts the "The count value is at least 1"

Comment: maybe your need parenthesis document.getElementsByClassName("bubble").innerHTML will give you the inner html document.getElementsByClassName("bubble").innerHTML == "0" will give you true or false probably you need var value = (document.getElementsByClassName("bubble").innerHTML == "0");

Comment: @EvikGhazarian Unfortunatley this didn't help. I have also tried it with innerText

Comment: what is the output of console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("bubble").innerHTML);

Comment: @EvikGhazarian undefined

Comment: that means your dom doesnt have the definition for the innerhtml. fix that first then move on to comparing it with zero or non-zero